# While loop not stoping I don't Know why (Solved)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I dont understand why My while loop does not stop when continue is pressed (continue is a variable)

```
continue = 'w'
def forest():
    while True:
       Walk = input("Ok " + name + " and " + dogName + ". you are in a epmty region of a the 
forest! What will you do?\n TYPE W TO MOVE FORWARD\n")
       if Walk.lower() == Continue:
           print("FORWARD you go")
           Break
       else:
          print("I don't understand try again\n")
          clear()
```

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: Also, what is the value of Continue

Comment: Could you reformat the code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need a break statement within the while loop.

Example:

```
def forest():
     Keep_Asking = "yes"
     while Keep_Asking == "yes":
          Walk = input("Ok " + name + " and " + dogName + ". you are in a epmty region of a the forest! What will you do?\n TYPE W TO MOVE FORWARD\n")
          if Walk is not None:
              break
if Walk.lower() == Continue:
print("FORWARD you go")
Keep_Asking = "no"
```

Comment: Please wait for the OP to update the indentation. Without proper indentation there is no way to know what the OP actually has.

Comment: And `input` always returns a string, so this loop will never run more than once.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Keep_Asking` is not modified inside the while loop, so it always has the value "yes" assigned. Perhaps you should indent the `if Walk.lower() == Continue` block so it performs that check inside the loop?

Comment: Please wait for the OP to update the indentation. Without proper indentation there is no way to know what the OP actually has.